# install monkeytalk on the armv7 armv7s architecture get the error Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Tags: armv7, monkeytalk

I'm making all steps by [this link](https://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk-documentation/monkeytalk-getting-started/install-agent/ios) and at finish have this error *"Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1"*.

Architecture of this project is **armv7 armv7s**. Someone have that problem?

Comment: I resolved this problem so:
1. In main project -> Build Settings scroll and find out the options, C++ Language Dialect and C++ Standard Library. Select options "Compiler Default" for both of them. (This is the step I missed, It is needed because newest XCode template has compiler default settings different to what they were in older versions).
2. "Build Valid Architecture Only" flag set as NO

Comment: 3. removed all in the Build Phases -> Run Script

Comment: Would you mind changing that comment to an answer so others can easily find it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your exact problem but I met a same kind of error and I resolved it like below.

Did you try to execute monkeytalk tests on a simulator after make a build from a shell script if so you have to add architecture for simulator "i386" . Here is a command that works for me

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -target FuncTest CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx" PROVISIONING_PROFILE="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX" OTHER_LDFLAGS="-lxml2 -all_load -lstdc++" DSTROOT="build" VALID_ARCHS="armv7 armv7s i386" -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 -configuration Release clean build install;
```

Note: this command should be execute in shell from the directory contains xcode project file.